# How to solve socket.io 0.9+ Cross domain

Tags: socket.io

I use socket. IO to do a chat application, the client is 0.8.4 and running normally. But when I put the socket. 0.9.4 IO upgrade to find the cross domain problem, other documents did not change, the following is wrong content:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/socket.io/1/? T = 1333528698474. http://mydomain.com Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Some people have the same problem? Or who know solution? Thank humbly!

Comment: I'm dealing with the same issue. I started in 0.9 though so I don't know if it works.

I'm hoping I can make it work by playing with the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set the [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP_access_control) header to your URL in the response.

NodeJS sample using [`setHeader`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value):

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','http://mydomain.com');
// or
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got mine working by using http:// in my browser address bar instead of file://

This was my issue: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/776